# Bluez 5.23 -> Bluez 5.43 - Bluetooth connected but no sound

Tags: python, bluetooth, raspberry-pi3, dbus, bluez

I would like to share with you a little problem on my RPI3 (Jessie distribution), hope someone could help me in this weird situation !

## My problem

I have a program which enables my **Rasperry Pi 3** (RPI3) to connect with a **Bluetooth speaker** and **get audio from it**. When I upgrade from **Bluez 5.23** to **Bluez 5.43** to get the awesome BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy) features (more for the GATT Server, which is not available in 5.23 zip), **BLE works** fine but the ** audio from the bluetooth speaker doesn't work** anymore. **I can connect to the bluetooth speaker, but I have no audio on it**.
My program works with the -C flag into /etc/systemd/system/dbus-org.bluez.service

### Error I get

This is the error I get now from running the program :
`Error processing request: Timeout exceeded. <pexpect.pty_spawn.spawn object at 0x75962490> command: /usr/bin/bluetoothctl args: ['/usr/bin/bluetoothctl'] buffer (last 100 chars): ']\x1b[0m# Device F4:4E:FD:AA:EB:10 not available\r\n\x1b[0;94m[bluetooth]\x1b[0m# ' before (last 100 chars): ']\x1b[0m# Device F4:4E:FD:AA:EB:10 not available\r\n\x1b[0;94m[bluetooth]\x1b[0m# ' after: <class 'pexpect.exceptions.TIMEOUT'> match: None match_index: None exitstatus: None flag_eof: False pid: 2899 child_fd: 22 closed: False timeout: 30 delimiter: <class 'pexpect.exceptions.EOF'> logfile: None logfile_read: None logfile_send: None maxread: 2000 ignorecase: False searchwindowsize: None delaybeforesend: 0.05 delayafterclose: 0.1 delayafterterminate: 0.1 searcher: searcher_re: 0: re.compile("bluetooth") 1: EOF` and
``

### What I tried

1. First I would like to say that I didn't do any command except the one I'll write below :

   - `sudo apt-get --only-upgrade bluez`

By upgrading bluez, I see into the command line that apt-get Install new version of three config files :

- /etc/bluetooth/input.conf
- /etc/bluetooth/main.conf
- /etc/dbus-1/system.d/bluetooth.conf

I didn't change those files, only look into the difference between the downgrade version and the "new" one into this website :

- https://www.apt-browse.org/browse/debian/stretch/main/amd64/bluez/5.43-2+deb9u1/
- https://www.apt-browse.org/browse/debian/jessie/main/amd64/bluez/5.23-2+deb8u1/
  But nothing alerts me.
  So I try to downgrade my Bluez version to the previous one by doing sudo apt-get install bluez=5.23..
  and everything was working fine.

Really that's a weird problem. Hope someone can help me with this !

Comment: You might have more success with this question over on https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ . Is there a reason you are not doing a [full-upgrade](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/raspbian/updating.md)? Newer versions of BueZ often require newer versions of the kernel.

Comment: Thank you very much ukBaz for your fast answer !! I'll post it on RPI too thx. 
I didn't want to upgrade my debian version, and worse changing from Jessie to another distribution. If I can find the solution without changing debian version, it would be perfect. Because I find that weird that it's only the audio which is affected, while the bluetooth works. Otherwise, I would upgrade like you advise me !

Comment: Then I wonder if you need to look at Linux backports https://backports.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page

Comment: Again, thank you for your fast answer, I'll look into it immediately